# About without surname Indian passport for Russia private invitation and visa

Tags: visas, passports, russia, invitation-letters

I got a private invitation from Russia,  the problem is on my passport  given name is Ajit pal singh and I have no surname,  but my Russian invitation my name mention on surname coloum is ajitpal and given name coloum mention is singh in Russian language  but automatically my name is mention is according to my passport Ajit pal singh  is it OK  that thing plz help me bcoz I so worry  about that!   M attached my passport n invitation with my name [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIeAv.jpg)[image]

Comment: That is totaly ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly OK. Many countries do not have any significant number of people who do not have surnames, so when transcribing such names into their computers they may take a variety of approaches, because their computers require something to appear in each field. For example, if you were to obtain a US visa, the the visa would show "FNU" in the given name field and your entire name would appear in the surname field. It is likely that something similar will happen with your name printed on your airline ticket, as their computers also require given names and surnames. As long as your entire name is there in either field and matches the name in your passport, it should be no problem.

Comment: That's urs means  my name on invitation is correct according to my passport name right?